# Drag starts too slow

Tags: windows-8.1, drag-and-drop

Recently when I want to drag an item, it starts way too slow.  I drag a folder, then a second or two later, the folder snaps to the mouse.  I recorded the process.

[Video](https://youtu.be/waJeLHGeXnw).

Not sure what changed...it started happening recently.  Anyway to fix it?

Comment: What's your PC setup?

Comment: Can you post here how did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue and I really don't know what else should I try. Thanks!

Comment: @sczdavos I simply rebooted the box...  I checked AlainD answer cause it would also be a cause for the problem, but in my case it was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, you should check your system is not running at high CPU usage (load Task Manager by right-clicking the taskbar). Have a look in [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]. There are a bunch of fancy-named settings in there that might be of interest. I've copied my settings which you could compare with your own in case there is a big difference. The setting "ClickLockTime" might be relevant.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragHeight"="4"
"CoolSwitchColumns"="7"
"ActiveWndTrackTimeout"=dword:00000000
"MouseCornerClipLength"="6"
"MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed"=dword:00000000
"DragWidth"="4"
"WallpaperStyle"="10"
"ScreenSaveActive"="0"
"TileWallpaper"="0"
"WheelScrollLines"="3"
"Pattern"=dword:00000000
"FontSmoothingType"=dword:00000002
"WindowArrangementActive"="1"
"BlockSendInputResets"="0"
"MenuShowDelay"="8"
"ClickLockTime"=dword:000004b0
"CaretWidth"=dword:00000001
"FocusBorderWidth"=dword:00000001
"WallpaperOriginX"=dword:00000000
"WallpaperOriginY"=dword:00000000
"DragFullWindows"="0"
"CoolSwitchRows"="3"
"ForegroundFlashCount"=dword:00000007
"LeftOverlapChars"="3"
"ForegroundLockTimeout"=dword:00030d40
"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:00000000
"DragFromMaximize"="1"
"FontSmoothing"="0"
"FocusBorderHeight"=dword:00000001
"WheelScrollChars"="3"
"DockMoving"="1"
"SnapSizing"="1"
"CursorBlinkRate"="600"
"MouseWheelRouting"=dword:00000001
"RightOverlapChars"="3"
"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:00000001
"PaintDesktopVersion"=dword:00000001
"Win8DpiScaling"=dword:00000001
"UserPreferencesMask"=hex:90,12,03,80,10,00,00,00
"AutoColorization"=dword:00000000
"Wallpaper"="C:\\Users\\Alain\\Pictures\\Desktop\\DSC_4279.JPG"
"MaxVirtualDesktopDimension"=dword:00000a00
"MaxMonitorDimension"=dword:00000a00
"TranscodedImageCount"=dword:00000001
"LastUpdated"=dword:ffffffff
"ImageColor"=dword:92b33647
"DesktopDPIOverride"="-2"
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060
"AutoEndTasks"="1"
"HungAppTimeout"="1000"
"WaitToKillAppTimeout"="2000"
"LowLevelHooksTimeout"="1000"
"SmoothScroll"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: MouseWheelRouting was wrong in my case. Thanks!